# Passing different arguments to different hosts in Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I am writing a script to launch a load generation experiment on several hosts. I could write a bash script to start multiple ssh sessions, but I was hoping to use something more structured. Since I use Python for most of my scripting, I thought [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org) looked like a good option.

The only problem is that I need to pass a small amount of host specific data with each command (really just an id or counter), and I would like to run them in parallel.

In other words, I would like to do something like the following, where host_num is different (possibly just incremented) for each host.

```
@parallel
def launch():
    with cd('/working/dir'):
        run("./start/script -id=%d", host_num)
```

Is this possible in Fabric? If not, is there another tool I could use to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check against user / host. Each task knows about environment they currently run in:

```
env.hosts = ['user@host1.com', 'user@host2.com']

@task
def test():
    print '%(user)s@%(host)s' % (env)

    if env.host == 'host1.com':
        id = 1
    elif ...

    run('echo "%s"' % (id))
```

Feel free to write it in more elegant way :) (one suggestion being dictionaries used similar to case statements for the id lookup)

Comment: Thanks. It's too bad there's not a better mechanism -- this method doesn't seem to work too well if you want to run the same script on different sets of host.

Comment: Will this still run in parallel? I have the same challenge, but I have 20 hosts, which are spun up at run time (AWS EC2 instances). So, I don't think hard coding the `if-then` statements ahead of time would work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want some introspection about what host you're running on inside the task, I'll suggest referencing the env.host variable. Each task knows about it's env state, though in parallel they do not share this state, since they're all running as forks. There are also a [number of other env vars](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/usage/env.html) at your disposal.