# Pass command line arguments for fabric execute task

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, fabric

I'm new to the `fabric` API and I'm trying to figure out to pass command line arguments, which are different for each host. So, here's where I'm at right now. Currently, the bit below runs the script `get_num_reviews_aws.py` correctly, in parallel, on each of the three hosts.

```
hosts = [ubuntu@54.xxx.xx.xx,
         ubuntu@52.xx.xxx.xx,
         ubuntu@54.xx.xxx.xx]

#%%
from fabric.api import run, parallel
from fabric.tasks import execute


%%
@parallel
def webscraper():
    run("python get_num_reviews_aws.py")


#%% run on hosts
execute(webscraper, hosts=hosts)
```

What I'm looking for is to be able to pass command line arguments to the python script, which are different for each host, but still have then run in parallel. So something like this:

```
@parallel
def webscraper(start, end):
    run("python get_num_reviews_aws.py %s %s" % (start, end))
```

and then basically have a different set of `start` and `end` for each host. What's hanging me up is I pass a list of hosts but I don't think I pass a list for each command line arguments, like:

```
start = [1, 2, 3]
end = [4, 5, 6]

execute(webscraper, start, end, hosts=hosts)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, after looking at a few other [similar questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602084/passing-different-arguments-to-different-hosts-in-fabric?answertab=votes#tab-top).

```
hosts = [ubuntu@54.xxx.xx.xx,
         ubuntu@52.xx.xxx.xx,
         ubuntu@54.xx.xxx.xx]


#%% get username and host
hosts = ["ubuntu@" + ip.ip_address for ip in instance_lst]


#%% Create my command line arguments and store them in a dict
# use the hostname as the key and store arguments in a tuple
host_dict = {host: (0, 10 + x) for x, host in enumerate(hosts)}


#%%
from fabric.api import run, parallel, env
from fabric.tasks import execute


#%% set environment
env.hosts = hosts


#%%
@parallel
def webscraper(host_dict):
    host = "ubuntu@" + env.host # cuts off the username, so have to re-add
    start_end = host_dict[host] # get the start and end for each host
    run("python get_num_reviews_aws.py %s %s" % start_end)


#%% run on hosts
# since I stored the hosts in an environment, don't need to pass hosts
execute(webscraper, host_dict)
```